# Speed up MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing some profiling & optimization of my MongoDB server, and have found that 99% of my slow queries (>100ms, per the [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)) are due to a single query in my node.js code.

First off, here's how I've modeled my cache (via mongoose):

```
{
                    '_id':                      { type: String, unique: true},
                    'group':                    { type: String, index: true },
                    'post_time_msec':           { type: Number, index: true },
                    'stream_type':              { type: String },
                    'stream_name':              { type: String },
                    'stream_id':                { type: String },
                    'stream_key':               { type: String },
                    'last_updated':             { type: Date },
                    'data':                     {},
                    'bookmarks':                { type: Number },
                }
```

Now, for my query which is slow.
I look for objects which fall within a certain "group" field. That is, I want to find the "post_time_msec" of all objects within a group so I can tell if I need to update those objects.

The query, in node.js and mongo, looks like this:

```
var thegroup = ... // this is set earlier
model.find({'group': thegroup}, {'_id': true, 'post_time_msec': true}, {'limit': 300, 'sort': {'post_time_msec': -1}});
```

I also clean up the collection frequently, deleting extra objects when there are more than 300 in the collection belonging to a certain group (this way, the query should not be looking through thousands of records...)

When I look at the mongo profiler, here's an example of the query running slowly:

```
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-03T05:00:29.802Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "streamified.postcaches", "query" : { "query" : { "group" : "network/group/2934jq98239oeu1" }, "orderby" : { "post_time_msec" : -1 } }, "ntoreturn" : 300, "nscanned" : 305, "scanAndOrder" : true, "nreturned" : 300, "responseLength" : 31520, "millis" : 985, "client" : "10.179.35.87", "user" : "" }
```

As you can see, this query took nearly 1 full second to complete. It only scanned 305 rows and only returned 2 fields, and all the query fields are indexed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: add a compound index on `group` and `post_time_msec` in that order

Comment: Can you include the results of an `explain()` on the query?  It looks like this query is doing a full scan of the collection (i.e. you are probably missing the index suggested by @JonathanOng).  Additionally, for your cache you should consider either using a [Capped Collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) (which is a fixed-size collection with LRU expiry) or a [TTL Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) (explicit Time-To-Live expiry for MongoDB 2.2 or higher).

Comment: I've added the compound index in the following manner: db.cache.ensureIndex({'group':1,'post_time_msec':-1});

I hope this is correct, given that I want the post_time_msec to sort in a descending fashion, per my query. Regarding Capped Collections... I don't think I can do this because I need the cap to apply per-group, not per-collection, no? And for TTL, I can't do this because I don't know how old the oldest object will be; I need to ensure that at least 300 objects are cached, regardless of max-age.

Comment: if you don't ever plan to query more than a single group at a time, you can create a capped collection for each group and make each group a collection.

Comment: That is interesting, something I had not considered. This would have the added benefit of keeping each collection small and manageable, rather than [number of users] * 300 (since there is at least 1 group created per user of my app). I think I'll try to implement this tomorrow....

Comment: yup. and you will only need a single index `post_time_msec` which should save memory as well

Comment: @JonathanOng just wanted to check in and say this is working great. I've reduced my CPU-wait time from about 20% to almost 0% and improved overall performance drastically. If you wanted to write an answer here I'd accept it. However, I am having trouble with capped collections not performing correctly, if you'd like to chime in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729555/mongodb-capped-collection-not-removing-documents

Comment: i know nothing about capped collections and i do not care for meaningless points :P

Comment: question though: if you're splitting each group into its own collection, does indexing even help? 300 isn't a large collection, and i'm guessing you want to retrieve all 300 records anyways, so they should all be put in memory.

Comment: Interesting point, and I can't say I know the answer. The reason I kept the post_time_msec index is that I sort on this field, because I want the data ordered when I parse it in my handler function. I was under the impression that indexes helped with sorting, but I'll need to read more...

Comment: So, after a few days of working great, I ran into the MongoDB limitation that you can only have 24k collections. I'm trying to get around this by increasing the namespace size, but I wish I had foreseen this, since my servers are currently down as I try to upgrade the databases @.@