# MongoDB Capped Collection not removing documents

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to cap a collection at 1MB or 300 records, whichever came first.

```
PRIMARY>db.runCommand({"convertToCapped":"cache",'size':1024*1024, 'max':300});
{ "ok" : 1 }
PRIMARY>db.cache.isCapped();
true
```

So far so good.
A while later I check back in, after the collection has been used a bit (new records inserted, etc.)

```
PRIMARY> db.cache.count();
513
```

Um, what? Last time I checked, 513 > 300.
Note that the "capping" was executed before the count exceeded 300.

```
PRIMARY> db.cache.validate();
{
"ns" : "streamified.cache",
"capped" : 1,
"max" : 2147483647,
"firstExtent" : "16:7279e000 ns:streamified..tmp.convertToCapped.cache",
"lastExtent" : "16:7279e000 ns:streamified..tmp.convertToCapped.cache",
"extentCount" : 1,
"datasize" : 858104,
"nrecords" : 513,
"lastExtentSize" : 1052672,
"padding" : 1,
"firstExtentDetails" : {
    "loc" : "16:7279e000",
    "xnext" : "null",
    "xprev" : "null",
    "nsdiag" : "streamified..tmp.convertToCapped.cache",
    "size" : 1052672,
    "firstRecord" : "16:7279e0b0",
    "lastRecord" : "16:72871444"
},
"deletedCount" : 1,
"deletedSize" : 186184,
"nIndexes" : 0,
"keysPerIndex" : {

},
"valid" : true,
"errors" : [ ],
"warning" : "Some checks omitted for speed. use {full:true} option to do more thorough scan.",
"ok" : 1
}
```

I'm not great at reading this output, but the "max" value above looks a bit weird. Other than that, I'm not sure what could be going wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the max option is not supported on the convertToCapped method.

The docs do not mention it.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/

max is only an option on new collections.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. What a shame, this completely kills my ability to use Capped Collections, because of a bug in mongoose 2.7.1 preventing me from creating a capped collection at the definition time.